# What is the sample space in this conditional quiz

Tags: probability

The answer to this quiz baffles me: {t,1,2,3,4,5,6}

Q. I play a game. Toss a coin, if I get a head then I roll a die. What are the possible sample points.

A. {1,2,3,4,5,6}
B. {t,1,2,3,4,5,6}
c. None of the above

I had thought {h, 1,2,3,4,5,6} would be the case and then I said C - none of the above.

Any help why the condition seems interpreted  wrongly , well according to me.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you flip tails? You stop there. So $t$ is in your sample space.

What happens if you flip heads? You roll the die. So the results of rolling the die are also in your sample space, which are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. (You could argue that each of those results is actually the pair $(h, 1)$, $(h, 2)$, etc.).

So your total sample space is the set of $t$ and the die rolls $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$, so the answer is B.

Comment: You are correct, I have fixed that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. So I believe it's $\{T,H,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

You could if you want divide them up into two sets. The first one $\{T\}$ and only $T$. Because it doesnt include anything else. Then the final set: $\{H,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. But both sets are in the sample space to be frankly.